# How to access remotely different application servers on the same server machine?

Tags: asp.net, iis-6, windows-server-2003, tomcat5.5

I'm kind of new to application servers so here it goes. I have a NT machine which has Windows Server 2003 installed on it; it also has an Apache Tomcat 5.5 app server which some people use .JSP for some tasks. What I'm trying to do is that I want to install IIS to this machine for usage of some ASP.NET websites and configure it with a different port to prevent any conflicts; since the server is very important for some employees, I have to be careful and not to crash any of their data . So my questions are: 
1)Will those 2 servers interfere with each other so I have to do some extra setting?
2)How can I access those server pages on the same network, what to type on the browser(I can of course access it locally by providing ip and port)?

Comment: Hi, this is all about IIS configuration, does not belong here!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Install IIS and check what port(s) each server uses. If they are different they won't conflict.

2) The original address when testing on localhost being:

http://localhost:8500/Default.aspx

To access a site through the LAN you have to use address in the form:

192.168.1.5:8500/Default.aspx

192.168.1.5 being the LAN IP address which can be obtained from the cmd prompt by typing ipconfig

[image: example ipconfig]

And 8500 being the port on which the server is located.

Comment: thank you so much Răzvan Panda! That's exactly what I was looking for!